# how to set arbitrary registry without .nmprc file in git repository

Tags: azure, npm, npm-install

I have following situation - my project use on azure pipeline which build project using `npm install` (I not configure this - only use this pipeline - I have no acces to azure (except logs) - only to git). When .npmrc file (which contains my private registry for some my library, but without passwords) is in git repo - then build process is ok.

But there is problem, last time I accidently publish my passwords inside .npmrc file by push it to git repo (and I was forced to change passwords). So I decide to remove this file from git repository. But after that, saddly build process fails:

[image]

So I have Idea to put some .npmrc_template file (with registry but whithout password) and somehow give path to npm to that file - may be in package.json or maybe in some other way. But after reding documentation still not have clue how to do it (and even it is possible at all).

May be you have some idea how to set npm **registy** without using .npmrc file inside project directory on git repo (and without using npm user/global configuration which is not available on azuere pipeline used by my project) ?

Comment: You should be able to do: .npmrc_template: `registry=https://registry-url`, package.json: `"scripts": { "preinstall": "export NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG=./.npmrc_template && npm install" }`. don't include .npmrc in your repo